# Find a formula for $T$, and a basis for the image and kernel, given its standard matrix representation.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that $[T]_{can}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&1\\-1&3&4 \end{bmatrix}$.

Determine $T(x, y, z)$. Find a basis of $Im(T)$ and a basis of $Ker(T)$

---

$Im(T)$ is the column-space, which is the row-space of the matrix $[T]_{can}^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\2&1&3\\1&1&4 \end{bmatrix}$

but we can determine a basis of by putting it in row-reduced echelon form:

$[T]_{can}^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\2&1&3\\1&1&4 \end{bmatrix}$ $\to$ $\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1\\
0&1&5\\
0&1&5\end{bmatrix}$ $\to$  $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&5\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} $

So a basis of $Im(T)$ is {$(1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 5)$}

The $Ker(T)$ can be found by:

$[T]_{can}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&1\\-1&3&4 \end{bmatrix} \to  \begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&1\\0&5&5 \end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

So

$x-z = 0$ and $y + z = 0 \to x = z$ and $y = -z$
choosing $z = 1$ {$(1, 1, 1)$} is a basis for $Ker(T)$.

Is my proof correct?

Thanks.

Comment: $T[1,1,1]^T \neq 0$ so it's not in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct except :

- a basis of $Im(T)$ is $\{(1,0,\color{red}-1),(0,1,5)\}$;
- $(x,y,z)\in Ker(T) \iff \begin{cases}x+2y+z=0 \\ y+z=0\\ -x+3y+4z=0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}x+2y+z=0 \\ y+z=0\\ 5y+5z=0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}x=-2y-z=z \\ y=-z\end{cases}\iff (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}(1,\color{red}-1,1)$